# SharedPreferences do something if boolean is true

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am trying to show an image if a boolean is true. I did everything and there are no errors. I think there is something wrong in the code.

Here are my codes:

```
public class Question{
    boolean answered;
    public static int id;
    String userAnswer;
    String QuestionP = LogoQuiz.QuestionP;

    public Question(int i, Context context){
        SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(QuestionP, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        id = i;
        answered = pref.getBoolean("answered"+i, false);
    }
}
```

For putBoolean:

```
public static int pol;
    ------activity---------
    pol = (int) intent.getExtras().getInt("id");
        int i = pol;
            int id = new Question(i, Answer.this).id;
            editor.putBoolean("answered"+id, true).commit();
```

In another activity I want to do something if it is true:

```
int i1 = Answer.pol;
        int id = new Question(i1, Ques.this).id;
        if(pref.getBoolean("answered"+id, true))
        {
     ------ do something ------
        }
```

Can someone help me doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int id;
```

This variable shouldn't be static.  You don't want all questions to share one id, you want them each to have a unique id.  That's the root of your problem.

Comment: Oh, I changed it to int id, but how to get it from another activity? int id = new Question().id; ?

Comment: Yes.  Its now a variable in the question object, if its public you can access it from the question.  If you need to pass a question from one activity to another, you should do so via Intent.

Comment: I made some changes in the codes, now it works, but there is an activity it doesn't work in it.